re-install pass on Debian sid
pass was recently removed on my Debian sid setup when gpg (namely dirmngr gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpgsm gpgconf gpgv) were upgraded to unstable version 2.2.40-3.
At this time, reinstalling pass requires downgrading gpg to 2.2.40.1. Is there a clean way for me to downgrade without apt-get removing several other packages that I know should not be removed.
Error log:
#apt install pass
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

Unsatisfied dependencies:
gnupg :  Depends: dirmngr (< 2.2.40-1.1.1~) but 2.2.40-3 is to be installed
         Depends: gpg-agent (< 2.2.40-1.1.1~) but 2.2.40-3 is to be installed
         Depends: gpg-wks-client (< 2.2.40-1.1.1~) but 2.2.40-3 is to be installed
         Depends: gpg-wks-server (< 2.2.40-1.1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gpg-wks-server (>= 2.2.40-1.1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gpgsm (< 2.2.40-1.1.1~) but 2.2.40-3 is to be installed
Error: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

apt policy gnupg shows
gnupg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.2.40-1.1
  Version table:
     2.2.40-3 200
        […] sid/main […]
     2.2.40.1.1 500
        […] bookworm/main […]

I recently set testing to 500 pin-priority (with sid at 200) in /etc/apt/preferences to transition from sid -> testing as part of next Debian release.

The problem you’re running into comes from your switch to testing. It’s fine to do this, and thank you for helping test the next release; but usually it’s best done at a quieter time in the development process.
To fix your immediate problem, the safest option is to install gnupg from unstable:
sudo apt install -t sid gnupg

After that, given the current state of testing and unstable, you’ll have to keep an eye open for similar issues when upgrading. Essentially, you’ll be manually replicating the work done by britney2 and the release team.

Forcing apt to install gnupg from unstable does the trick. Thanks for your timely help as well as possible breaks from upcoming Debian release.
